# How to manage Youtube API v3 resumable upload that last more than one hour

Tags: api, youtube

So the problem I'm facing is uploading large video files trough **Youtube API v3.0**.
I'm folowing the steps specified [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol).

So I thought that the issue lies in access token, becouse it's valid only for 3600 seconds. So I got the refresh token from OAuth Playground. And I get the fresh token when user starts the upload on my Youtube channel. After 50 minutes i abort the **PUT** request, get the fresh token and resume upload like specified in documentation. The problem is that after one hour I get response:

```
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Everything works fine when upload lasts less than one hour. But when uploading big files on slow broadband the upload fails. What am I doing wrong?

I'm making the requests in JavaScript with jQuery. I double checked the steps in documentation, and if it works with smaller video i think the script is ok.

Even [this](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/yt-upload-javascript) script fails to upload after one hour, the progress bar comes to 100% but then it gets **401 response**.

Thank you for your time, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can try the script here http://fb.3art.si/youtube2/

Comment: This is a known issue that's being tracked internally and hopefully will be resolved in the near future.